# typescript augument interface from namespace declared in @types

Tags: typescript, namespaces

I'm trying to add the e.g. *responsive* property into e.g. interface *Settings* from e.g. node_modules/@types/datatables.net/index.d.ts:

```
declare namespace DataTables {
    ...
    interface Settings {
    ...
```

My project is based on https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter and I want to use that property with *datatables.net-responsive-bs4* which implements it.

Q: How would I write the declaration for adding the *responsive* property?

PS: I'm specifically interesting in learning how to write that kind of declaration into my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between augmenting a module and an ambient declaration. In your case the definitions for `datatables.net` just de declare a `namespace` and an `interface`. This means you can just redeclare these in another `d.ts` file and they will get merged:

```
// datatables.d.ts
declare namespace DataTables {

    interface Settings {
        responsive : boolean
    }
}

// usage.ts
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/datatables.net/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./datatables.d.ts" />

let settings : DataTables.Settings = {
    responsive: true, // ok, from us 
    autoWidth: true // from lib
}
```

For module augmentation you can have a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) in the module augmentation section.

PS: *tslint.json* should use at least `"allow-declarations"` for the rule `"no-namespace"` otherwise the IDE might trick you by invalidating the `declare` keyword (e.g. use `"no-namespace": [true, "allow-declarations"]`).